# How to archive this layout like shopkick using UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

As you can see in the picture, at some place one row takes up two column spaces. But as I know, UICollectionView only display item in multiple rows and columns. I don't want to use header and footer, because it appears randomly. I want to know how to do it, anyone can help me with that?

[image]

Comment: Check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: @Kalpesh but it didn't mention the layout like this.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViews using the default UICollectionViewFlowLayout keep on adding items to a row until an item no longer fits.

So in your sizeForItemAtIndexPath function, if you return

indexPath 0 -> CGSize(160,160)

indexPath 1 -> CGSize(160,160)

indexPath 2 -> CGSize(320, 160)

indexPath 3 -> CGSize(160,160)

indexPath 4 -> CGSize(160,160)

and so on....

The Collection view will display (assuming a collection view width of 320)
0, 1 
--2--
3, 4

Side not: the default behavior is to center elements if the entire width of a row is not taken up. So in the previous example if indexPath 2's width was 180, since it can't fit another 160 width item, the 180 width item would be centered in the middle of that row.